# Get path variable out of HttpMessageNotReadable exception

Tags: java, spring, variables, path, httpexception

We have some web services which are being consumed by mobile clients , in which the mobile clients make some request's and we return response to them. Somehow if the client make any invalid request we throw Custom `Exceptions` .
But recently the mobile client has made some request which was out of range for `Long` variable. 
 The client has different variables for ex ::

```
    {
      "accountId":"343"
      "Amount":"90909090909090909090"
    }
```

In case of the value for **accountId or Amount** are made more than 19 digits we get `HttpMessageNotReadable` exception as the range is out of long value. But from exception i am not able to fetch for which variable the exception has been raised whether for `accountId` or `Amount`. From the exception i am getting this information in `_path` variable but i am not able to fetch it.
[image]

And in the path variable i get something like::

```
[com.Upload["AccountInfo"], com.Info["Account"]]
```

Does somebody  know how to fetch this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code prints out the field which causes the exception.

```
InvalidFormatException invalidFormatException = (InvalidFormatException) exception
        .getCause();
System.out.println(invalidFormatException.getPath().get(0)
        .getFieldName());
```

Answer (score 1):

@ArunM's answer works as long as the field is in 1st level viz the example given by OP.

But what happens when the field is in nested json? say `paymentType` has wrong value in the following example?

```
{
  "userType": "CUSTOMER",
  "payment": {
                 "amount": 123456,
                 "paymentType": "INTERNET_BANKING"
              }
}
```

In the above example, if there's anything wrong with the value of `userType`, there will be just one element in `_path`.

But if any value inside the payment is wrong, say for example `paymentType`, there will be multiple elements in the `_path` variable. Each element representing the hierarchical attribute.

So for `paymentType`, `_path` will have 2 elements as illustrated below:

```
_path[0].fieldName = "payment"
_path[1].fieldName = "paymentType"
```

Hence the correct approach is to get the last element in `_path` as shown below. If needed, we can build the complete path by using all the elements.

```
InvalidFormatException ifx = (InvalidFormatException) exception.getCause();
System.out.println(ifx.getPath().get(ifx.size() - 1).getFieldName());
```

This I believe is the right approach to get the invalid attribute name.